# atftpd service start and removal error

Tags: linux, linux-networking, apt, linux-kernel

I am facing error while doing `apt --fix-broken install`
I searched on google but no luck.

```
After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 487600 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../atftpd_0.7.git20210915-3_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop atftpd.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
See system logs and 'systemctl status atftpd.service' for details.
dpkg: warning: old atftpd package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Fix broken syntax in /etc/default/atftpd
Failed to stop atftpd.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status atftpd.service' for details.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/atftpd_0.7.git20210915-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new atftpd package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed atftpd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/atftpd_0.7.git20210915-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: either force it or rm /etc/default/atftpd

Comment: `See system logs and 'systemctl status atftpd.service' for details.` did you do that?

Comment: yeah, i did that. I got `Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)`

Comment: I also tried to remove it. But still when i do `apt --fix-broken install` same error repeats